# How to get the crossvalidated prediction for each observation in Random Forest classification problem in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I would like to understand, how I can get the predicted value for each observation in a dataset through cross validation in python RandomForestClassifier.

I'm using code as below.
I wanted to understand if there was any more efficient way of  doing this? Including tuning the parameters for the trees. Please let me know.

```
X=data.predictors[:150]
y=data.target[:150]
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
y_pred = cross_val_predict(rfc, X, Y, cv=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it in 2 steps, first use gridsearchcv to tune your hyper parameters, for example:

```
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
X=iris.iloc[:,:4]
y=(iris['species'] == "versicolor").astype('int')

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=77)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=88,shuffle=True)

model_params = {
    'max_features': [1,2,3],
    'min_samples_split': [2, 4, 6]
}

clf = GridSearchCV(rfc, model_params,cv=skf)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

We find the parameter with the best result:

```
best_p = np.argmin(clf.cv_results_['rank_test_score'])
param = clf.cv_results_['params'][best_p]
param

{'max_features': 2, 'min_samples_split': 6}
```

Redefine the classifier and use cross_val_predict:

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=77,max_features=param['max_features'],
                             min_samples_split=param['min_samples_split'])
cross_val_predict(rfc, X, y, cv=skf)
```